# user_create.sh Ubuntu shell script

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

Hi I am writing a shell script for a school assignment but cant seem to get it to work as needed. Bellow is what I have so far. What I am aiming to do is add the account name e.g. Real name to the user account when it is created. Also a Cron tab which records disk usage at 11:59 daily and saves it to storage.log.

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=","

while read f1 f2 f3 f4

do  hostname $f1
    useradd $f2
    passwd $f3
    groupadd $f4

        #echo "Real name      : $f1"

        #echo "Username          : $f2"

        #echo "Default password        : $f3"

        #echo "Group Name      : $f4"

59 11 * * * sudo du >>/home/bond/Desktop/GroupActivities/storage.log
done < /home/bond/Desktop/GroupActivities/data.csv
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I assign the account name? e.g. Jon doe to jdoe

Answer (score 0):

`useradd` command has a flag that does exactly what you need, from `man useradd`:

```
   -c, --comment COMMENT
       Any text string. It is generally a short description of the login, and is currently used as the field for the user's full name.
```

Comment: Hi i dont understand this it still does not work. Can u edit the code I have provided